# pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, pr2-controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

When I execute:

> rosrun pr2_controller_manager
> pr2_controller_manager list

Nothing happens, no info or warning messages, it just seems to hang. When I ctrl+c the operation I get this output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 161, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 92, in main
    rospy.wait_for_service('pr2_controller_manager/load_controller')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 158, in wait_for_service
    raise ROSInterruptException("rospy shutdown")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: rospy shutdown
root@ubuntu:~# rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list
```

Anyone know what this could be from or referring to? Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54393/pr2_controller_manager-pr2_controller_manager-list/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-26**:
Hello Martin. I am now dealing the same problem as you had. The question is that, how do I use the Pr2_controller to move the base of my robot (non-pr2)? Do I have to include it as a plugin for Gazebo or what? Please help! Much appreciated!

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-05-28**:
Hello Gazer, I found that I did not need the plugin. However, I am using the Warehouse Viewer and ArmNavWizard to control my (non-pr2) robot's arms and not the base (which may use Gazebo?). To get my robot to work I had to set up the action servers: http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_trajectory_action

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-05-28**:
Basically, one of my programs sets up a joint_trajectory_action client that interacts with the left or right arm joint_trajectory_action server. The server then sends /commands to my robot-specific hardware driver. I hope this helps. I haven't learned much in the way of navigation, yet :) Cheers!

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-28**:
thank you very much! So I guess you didn't use the Pr2_controller or you didn't write any controller for your robot then? which tutorials do you recommend me to look at? I want to do it in Gazebo.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-06-26**:
Hey Gazer, sorry for the late reply I was away on vacation. I only used the controllers built into the control boards of my specific robot. They are OK, but I may need to write my own later on. If you are still looking for tutorials I think you can find some at http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you didn't have any PR2 controller running when you executed the command.

You can launch the PR2 first

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

Then execute the command, For example

```
rosfuerte@rosfuerte-K53SM:~$ rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list
base_controller ( running )
base_odometry ( running )
head_traj_controller ( running )
l_arm_controller ( running )
l_gripper_controller ( running )
laser_tilt_controller ( running )
r_arm_controller ( running )
r_gripper_controller ( running )
torso_controller ( running )
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-06**:
Using that launch command starts the pr2 controllers, how do I launch my own controllers for a non-pr2 robot?

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-06**:
Hey Ricky, I think I do have a controller running. My rostopic echo /l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/status is publishing an empty status list. I am using the action controller shown in my question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/54510/error-when-sending-from-trajclient/

**Comment by [Riss69](https://answers.ros.org/users/44713/riss69/) on 2019-08-11**:
Even after launching pr2 first pr2_controller_manager don't seem to ouput anything